# Excel to pandas, whitespace as row delimeter

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have some badly formatted Excel data that looks like this:

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc


aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

Is there a decent way to, using the white space as a delimiter, turn each segment into a pandas row with a default value to fix raggedness?

I'd like the end result to be something like this:

```
aaaa bbbb cccc "" 
aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are 2 white spaces in the example. How do you recognise that the white space is a delimiter or an empty cell?

Comment: They are one and the same in this case. Any empty cell can be considered a delimiter.

Comment: do you know what the maximum number of columns in the final could/would be? is it small and fixed?

Comment: I can have that counted in python beforehand but it won't be small. 20000+.

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry. I read rows. Probably around 30 max columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was able to get something that works by bringing the column in as a list, and then trying to pull out each section of the list separated by any number of `''` values. There may be a better way to do these things, but maybe the idea is helpful (and it does work for my example at least).

The sample data I used here is like yours, with another little chunk at the end. Hopefully I'm understanding it right.

```
l = ['aaaa',
'bbbb',
'cccc',
'',
'',
'',
'aaaa',
'bbbb',
'cccc',
'dddd',
'',
'asdf',
'badfd'
]
```

With that list `l`, the idea is to loop through the list for the number of `''` items, and  pull out the items between `lastspace` (the last blank-space value) and `thisspace` (the current blank-space value).

It needed some special handling for when there are multiple `''` values in a row. That is the `while thisspace == lastspace+1...` piece, which if that happens it will work to skip it and go to the next `''` value. Because of this, we want to increment our loop counter when we find these consecutives, and so our loop also has to be a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop (which can't handle manual increments).

`l.index()` gives a `ValueError` when it can't find the substring, and so when we have gone past the last `''`, we need this error-handling.

```py
d = []
lastspace = -1
i = 0
while i <= l.count(''):
    try:
        thisspace = l.index('',lastspace+1)
        while thisspace == lastspace+1:
            lastspace = thisspace
            thisspace = l.index('',lastspace+1)
            i += 1    
        d.append(l[lastspace+1:thisspace])
        lastspace = thisspace
        i += 1
    except ValueError:
        d.append(l[lastspace+1:])
        i += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The dataframe I get in the end looks like this:

```
      0      1     2     3
0  aaaa   bbbb  cccc  None
1  aaaa   bbbb  cccc  dddd
2  asdf  badfd  None  None
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following text file `test.txt` to simulate your inputs

```
aaaa bbbb cccc  aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
```

Is this correct?

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', delimiter = ' ', header = None)

    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
0   aaaa    bbbb    cccc    NaN     aaaa    bbbb    cccc    dddd
```

And to further process the dataframe

```
df = df.fillna('')
print(np.array(df.loc[0,:].to_list()).reshape(-1,4))

[['aaaa' 'bbbb' 'cccc' '']
 ['aaaa' 'bbbb' 'cccc' 'dddd']]
```